# Reset cache in Thin instances launched by Unicorn

Tags: ruby, caching, thin, unicorn

I have a Ruby webapp that caches some frequently used information in a lightweight layer, but there are times at which I want to reset the cache without restarting the entire process.

Before I started using Unicorn, I had a known list of ports that I could send a special HTTP request to reset the cache on each instance. However, under Unicorn, the Unicorn process handles all the HTTP requests and passes them off to the children processes individually.

Under this model, is there a simple mechanism to send a message to each of the launched instances to reset their caches?

Answer (score 1):

You could configure the workers to each listen to a unique port in addition to the main port in with after_fork and send requests to each of those ports. See [Unicorn::Configurator](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/Unicorn/Configurator.html) documentation.

Comment: Something like:

after_fork do |server, worker|
  Rails.cache.clear